# MarkLogic 8 - sort-order by path-index

Tags: marklogic

Is sort-order by path-index already supported in ML 8? I want to achieve similar to the below:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <sort-order collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/EO/CU/MO" type="xs:string" direction="ascending">
    <path-index>attritbutes//name</path-index>
  </sort-order>
</options>
```

If not, is there a way to achieve this? I have several elements with the same name from different parent nodes or from the root element so I can't use just

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <sort-order collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/EO/CU/MO" type="xs:string" direction="ascending">
    <element ns="" name="name"/>
  </sort-order>
</options>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_33716):

> The sort-order element must have one of a single element child, a single score child, a single field child, or a single json-property child.

So you can't have a path child, but there is a way. Create a field based on the path(s) you want to use, then sort based on that field.

Comment: Creating a field!! Great solution :)

Comment: As noted by @Dixit in a comment below, don't forget to create a `Field Range Index` based on your field! They are necessary for sorting. Also, when used for sorting, `field`'s can have no more than *one* include, and don't necessarily need *any* (you can use an explicit path for your field that points directly at the element to be sorted - necessary in my case as my whole approach was trying to avoid issues with multiple same localnames in a document, and includes will still return a `many items in sequence` forest error if there is more than one localname for what you're including).

Answer (score 2):

There is a schema bug in 8.0-1 so that sort-order/path-index does not validate.

However, the code implements support for sort-order/path-index, so if you don't validate the options, it should work.  It might be better, however, to use a field as Dave suggests so you can continue to use validation to check for errors.

The schema bug is fixed in 8.0-2.

Comment: "the code implements support for sort-order/path-index"


Is this true? I was not able to find any reference to this in the documentation (ML v9), and had no luck implementing it this way (I eventually resorted to @Dave's `field` solution).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Create a field on `'name'` element

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <sort-order type="xs:string" 
              collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
              direction="ascending">
    <field name="name"/>
  </sort-order>
</options>
```

Comment: While creating a field on `name` element, `create range index` (there is an option to create `range index` while defining `field`) also else an error will be thrown.

Comment: @Dixit important note! Field Range Indexes are necessary for sort (you create a field range index based on your field).

Comment: @FatehKhalsa Thanks, But I said the same thing in the comment :)